# Teamcity: building c# project stored in mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial, teamcity

I'm trying to perform a simple task with teamcity that is to pull project from one repository to another (created by teamcity) and build the project from the second repository using visual studio build mode. The problem I faced is when teamcity pulls updates it doesn't update working folder so it can't find .sln-file hence build fails. How to get it work?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using a second repository? Why not let TeamCity get the code from the first repository and build it directly?

At my workplace, we are using TeamCity with Mercurial like this (TeamCity gets the code directly from the "real" repository) and it works perfectly!

If you *really* need the second repository, you could do the pulling by script.
Set up TeamCity so that it only knows about the second repository, and that it pulls and builds from that.
Then, set up a scheduled task that pulls from the first repository to the second every few minutes.